# Separate ID and Class for JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In several jquery tutorials, separate `ID` and `Class` are used for `JS` and `CSS`. for example

```
<div id="test" class="test">TEST</div>
```

As `ID` is used in the jQuery code, and `Class` is used in `CSS`. To me it is easier to not introduce `Class` and use `ID` for CSS rule too. Is there any advantage to use css-less `ID` for javascript?

**EDIT:** Thanks folks! I know the difference between `ID` and `Class`; I am asking why some use separate `ID` and `Class` for `JS` and `CSS` when one is sufficient. Here, the matter is the necessity for uniqueness of `ID`. The case is separating JS and CSS tasks (while they are closely entangled).

**EDIT2:** As requested, I give a typical example: this [Tutorial](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CheckboxActions/). Look for `actionsBox`; `.actionsBox` has been used for `CSS` and `#actionsBox` for `JS`. As you can see there is only one `<div>` so `ID` would be enough for styling.

Comment: Could you link to examples of jQuery tutorials that use this pattern?

Comment: I don't remember several example I saw; but by a quick search I found an example.

Comment: The example you've posted uses both ID and Class in its css (check the source).

Comment: This is the CSS http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CheckboxActions/css/style.css; where is `#actionsBox`?

Comment: @Ali: cheers. Does [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9260299/20578) make any sense to you?

Comment: @Ali go to the page and press ctrl + u, the page which the example is hosted on uses both. Updated answer to meet the new criteria, I think.

Comment: Html5 approach http://toddmotto.com/data-js-selectors-enhancing-html5-development-by-separating-css-from-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** [@Sharon commented a link to a great article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260004/separate-id-and-class-for-js-and-css/9260299#comment11671312_9260230) that discusses the drawbacks of using `id` selectors in CSS.

One reason people might only use classes in CSS is the specificity of the `id` selector.

If you’ve got two style declarations for one element, and they specify different values for a property, then *the style declaration with the more specific selector* wins out.

For example:

#### HTML

```
<div id="test" class="special-test"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
#test {
    color: red;
}

.special-test {
    color: blue;
}
```

The ID selector trumps all other selectors for specificity (see http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity for the rules), so here, the `<div>` will be red.

People who added `class="test"` to the `<div>` would presumably have written this:

#### HTML

```
<div id="test" class="test special-test"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
.test {
    color: red;
}

.special-test {
    color: blue;
}
```

When both style declarations have selectors with the same specificity, the later declaration wins out, so here the `<div>` would be blue.

Personally, I’ve never found that to be a problem. In the first example, all you have to write to make the `<div>` blue is this:

```
#test.special-test {
    color: blue;
}
```

But I guess some people find this aspect of specificity unnecessarily complex, and so avoid it by only using class selectors in their CSS.

(And I assume they keep the `id` because it’s faster to retrieve a DOM element in JavaScript by `id` than by class.)

Comment: Definitely, it is faster to find DOM element by `ID`, but it will be slower if attaching `CSS` rules to that `ID`. This is what I am trying to understand! But I enjoyed your informative description :)

Comment: “it is faster to find DOM element by ID, but it will be slower if attaching CSS rules to that ID” — do you mean that using `id` selectors in your CSS will result in the styles being applied slower than if you’d used class selectors? Is that true?

Comment: I don't know! I just said it "might" be a reason for using ID for JS and Class for CSS. This is what I try to know.

Comment: Well, if we’re quoting then you said “it will be slower”, but I get what you mean. @Sharon’s oli.jp article has the best discussion of the performance of CSS selectors that I’ve seen.

Answer (score 5):

Read [“Don't use class names to find HTML elements with JS”](http://roytomeij.com/2012/dont-use-class-names-to-find-HTML-elements-with-JS.html) for some reasons why you may want to avoid using classnames in JavaScript.

This all boils down to personal preference, really.

Comment: It is not matter of personal preference when using both. There should be a reason to use both together.

Comment: In my example, we do not use class for JS. The debate is where using the same `ID` for `CSS` or introducing `Class` for `CSS`

Comment: @Ali Did you read the article I linked to? The bottom line is that using e.g. only IDs for JS and only classnames for CSS makes your code more flexible. You can go and edit classnames in your HTML and you know you’ll have to tweak the CSS too, but none of the JS will break. If you change an ID in the HTML, no styling will break, but the JS will need to be changed accordingly. See? It doesn’t really matter what you decide; what’s important is that once you’ve agreed on a coding style, you stick to it.

Comment: Yes, I read it; though it took a while `;)` as it was a long article with interesting comments. Like many similar articles, it says that using `Class` will slow down JS as it needs to search for all matching elements. The point is why not using `ID` for `CSS`. And I don't think that `ID` has been created for the sake of `JS` ... it is essential built of HTML for structuring (including CSS).

Comment: personally, i strongly disagree with this article and wouldn't recommend it. The performance issue is too heavy to just ignore it, especially in IE.

Comment: Using IDs in CSS increases specificity, which may or may not lead to issues. In that aspect, consistently using classes is easier. See http://oli.jp/2011/ids/#specifity-wars (another long article; sorry!)

Comment: @Sharon actually, you are good in finding articles :) and I enjoy reading long articles :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use both ID and Class with both javascript and css. For example:

CSS

```
/*ID as identifier*/
#some_id {
    <css attributes>
}

/*Class as identifier*/
.some_class {
    <css attributes>
}
```

Javascript:

```
/*Get by ID*/
document.getElementById("some_id");
/*Get by class*/
document.getElementsByClassName("some_class");
```

The difference between the two is that ID will, or at least should be, unique and therefore will only affect or return a single element when applying css rules or selecting via javascript respectively. Class on the other hand is for affecting or selecting elements of a similar nature or classification.

If you had a car park with ten cars in it and you were to say "I want the car in space number three" you'd expect a single return whereas were you to say "I want the Fords from the car park" you'd expect to return every car in the car park which was a Ford. Css and javascipt use of ID and Class is no different.

EDIT: As per the OP's new redefined line of questioning.

css and IDs:

Css can harness IDs as an anchor so that the contents of a uniquely identified DOM object. Consider the folowing piece of css.

```
#some_id tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#666888;
}
```

In the above example the css is tied to a unique identifier which in this case the ID is assigned to a table but the css rules themselves are applied to the odd rows within the table. In other words the css in this case affects table row elements where TR itself is an object class (not to be confused with css class).

In short, for ID at least, it is useful to use IDs within css and when you consider that jQuery and the likes of support Class-based queries using Class for selection within javascript is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

Curious about the dual nature of "ID" in javascript and CSS.  If you visit this example from w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_blocks
you'll see the  which is "naming" this particular <div> with the name "myDiv".  This is because javascript getElementById("myDiv") is used later to modify the text contents of this specific <div>

BUT - if you add the line of code:
<style> #myDiv { color:blue; } </style>

you now have a CSS id with the same name as the javascript <div id>

The sample code in the w3schools does indeed change the color of the <div> called "myDiv" to blue.  But when you push the "try it" button on that page, the CONTENTS of the javascript <div> also changes, which is the point of the w3schools example.  Ie., it's teaching you that getElementById("myDiv") is how you can retrieve and modify contents of a named <div>

But because the identically named CSS #myDiv id is in force the <div> contents are changed, and they remain blue due to the style sheet.
So when you see a <div id="myDiv"> inside an HTML page, how can you readily tell if this <div> wants CSS id treatment?  Or if this <div> will be referenced by some javascript getElementById() method?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should check out the differenc between ID's and Classes:

- http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

I have never heard of using classes only in CSS and ID's only for JavaScript.

The main thing is ID's are unique, thats why they are called identifiers. If you have the same styling of a div over and over again on your webpage you should use a class to style them.

EDIT: It's not common or maybe its not allowed, I'm not sure, that ID's start with a number !

Comment: @EvilP [IDs can start with a number](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class), but then [you’ll have to escape it correctly when using it in a selector](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) (e.g. when targeting the element in CSS). Example: [`id="404-error"`](http://mothereff.in/css-escapes#0404-error).

Answer (score -2):

Id should(read: must) be unique. A class is a set of object that have similarities, for example all lists on the page should look the same (but then you should use the list selector instead of a seperate class for it.

They have different purposes.

Comment: s/should/must; at least when you involve javascript non-unique ids will break things

Comment: The browser will render it even tough you have the same IDs. But to prevent problems you need to use unique IDs!

Comment: It will render it - but some javascripts are likely to break in this case.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `id` and / or `class` in JS and / or CSS. It all depends what you want to select.  If you want to select a single DOM element, feel free to use `id`. If you want to select a group of related elements you might be better off using `class`.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, why don't you comment so we know what you think is inaccurate about it?